# powershell json print parent and children

Tags: json, powershell

Given:

```
$j = '{"name": "fred", "age":23, "children": [{"name": "sue", "age": 2},{"name": "Sally", "age": 3}]}'
```

I can do this:

```
> $f = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $j
> $f.children

name  age
----  ---
sue     2
Sally   3
```

What I want is output like

```
> $f. #what goes here?

name  child  age
----  ---
fred  sue     2
fred  Sally   3
```

How would I do that?

update, tried this:

```
> $child = @{label="child";expression={$_.children.name}}
> $age = @{label="age";expression={$_.children.age}}
> $f | select name, $child, $age
```

Got

```
name child        age
---- -----        ---
fred {sue, Sally} {2, 3}
```

Not quite what I'm looking for.  (I want two lines with one child per  line and the parent's name)

Comment: See: `Select-Object`, particularly the section in the docs about calculated properties.

Comment: Thanks I followed that example but no joy.  I updated the top post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt is close.  I would recommend iterating the children under the key:

```
foreach ($child in $f.children) {
    $f | Select-Object -Property @(
        'name'
        @{L='child'; E={ $child.name }}
        @{L='age';   E={ $child.age  }}
    )
}
```

An alternative approach without the loop:

```
$name = $f.name
$f.children | Select-Object -Property @(
    @{L='name';  E={ $name   }}
    @{L='child'; E={ $_.name }}
    'age'
)
```

Lastly, another approach entirely (based on the both methods):

```
$name = $f.name
foreach ($child in $f.children) {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        name  = $name
        child = $child.name
        age   = $child.age
    }
}
```