# POWERSHELL - JSON - outputing parent and child nodes together

Tags: json, powershell

started to learn PS and got stuck on how to use Select-Object and Calculated Properties. Could you please help.

**GIVEN**
a nested JSON-file of the following structure:

```
{
    "asn": "111",
    "cartons": [
        {
            "carton": "00300000000000000001",
            "items": [
                {
                    "gtin": "04000000000001",
                    "serials": [
                        {
                            "serial": "gQ6;66/Iokpa0"
                        },
                        {
                            "serial": "1JFgKK,ImIwH\""
                        },
                        {
                            "serial": "feDiSStPwQSr3"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "carton": "00300000000000000002",
            "items": [
                {
                    "gtin": "04000000000002",
                    "serials": [
                        {
                            "serial": "bMG-u2jCc4LfM"
                        },
                        {
                            "serial": "KEOHZ6enUPT)6"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "carton": "00300000000000000003",
            "items": [
                {
                    "gtin": "04000000000003",
                    "serials": [
                        {
                            "serial": "344r,I1n3o:Gn"
                        },
                        {
                            "serial": "N:NYiBXGYCQl("
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**QUESTION 1** How to output the list:

```
GTIN              SERIAL
----              ------
04000000000001    gQ6;66/Iokpa0
04000000000001    1JFgKK,ImIwH"
04000000000001    feDiSStPwQSr3
04000000000002    bMG-u2jCc4LfM
04000000000002    KEOHZ6enUPT)6
04000000000003    344r,I1n3o:Gn
04000000000003    N:NYiBXGYCQl(
```

**QUESTION 2** How to output the list:

```
CARTON                  GTIN              SERIAL
------                  ------            ------
00300000000000000001    04000000000001    gQ6;66/Iokpa0
00300000000000000001    04000000000001    1JFgKK,ImIwH"
00300000000000000001    04000000000001    feDiSStPwQSr3
00300000000000000002    04000000000002    bMG-u2jCc4LfM
00300000000000000002    04000000000002    KEOHZ6enUPT)6
00300000000000000003    04000000000003    344r,I1n3o:Gn
00300000000000000003    04000000000003    N:NYiBXGYCQl(
```

**QUESTION 3** How to output the concatenation of PARENT & CHILD nodes with additional insertions:

```
GTIN+SERIAL
------------
(01)04000000000001(21)gQ6;66/Iokpa0
(01)04000000000001(21)1JFgKK,ImIwH"
(01)04000000000001(21)feDiSStPwQSr3
(01)04000000000002(21)bMG-u2jCc4LfM
(01)04000000000002(21)KEOHZ6enUPT)6
(01)04000000000003(21)344r,I1n3o:Gn
(01)04000000000003(21)N:NYiBXGYCQl(
```

**MY ATTEMPTS**

First, I played with with `-expandProperty`

```
$asn = convertFrom-Json -inputObject $j #actually, in the full code don't need this conversion, use Invoke-RestMethod
$asn.cartons.items | select-object -property gtin -expandProperty serials
```

Then tried to adopt the code from [powershell json print parent and children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57629283/powershell-json-print-parent-and-children) and [how to combine properties from objects and their "parent" object?](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/3a0r2s/how_to_combine_properties_from_objects_and_their/) but had no success.

Then got through about_Calculated_Properties - again just simple examples.

Then:

```
$asn = convertFrom-Json -inputObject $j
$asn.cartons.items | ForEach-Object {
$gtin = $_.gtin 
$serials = $_.serials | ForEach-Object {
        [pscustomobject] @{
            'gtin' = $gtin
            'serial' = $_.serial
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you attempted to write any code to do this yourself? You'll typically get asked this question when posting on here. Try posting your attempt as well.

Comment: Try at least an attempt of doing this and we can help you if you're stuck.

Comment: Added my attempts.

Answer (score 1):

I wont give you a direct answer, but some guidance (mainly because this really looks like some questions from a test). however:

when you invoke `select-object` (im going to be using just `select` for brevity) you have the option to do 'calculated property'. for this to work you need 2 things:
**name** or `n` for defining the actual value for the property
**expression** or `e`, a scriptblock used in the same manner as when you do `foreach-object` or `where-object`.

also I can see that all of the results you want is dependent on looping through the array `cartons`, so we will use this as the loop:

```
$Othervalue = "some other value"
Foreach($carton in $json.cartons)
{
    $carton|select @{n='gtin';e={$_.items.gtin}},@{n='othervalue';e={$othervalue}}
}
```

what happens here is that i select the property items, from the current object `$carton`, and then `gtin`.
powershell really doesn't care that the `items` object is an array. If it finds out that one of the items in `items` array has a property called `gtin`, it will return that value. if it finds several, then it will return a array of `gtin` values. how this is handled is up to you, but from your examples there is only one `gtin` property. you will quickly notice this then you try to retrieve the serial value.

The `othervalue` is just to show that you can also show values from outside of the "just this item" scope.

now if you want to have it output values for each of the items inside `items` and `serial` as well, you might have to do something like a foreach inside a foreach inside a foreach and that can get messy pretty quick, so my suggestion is to use `foreach($item in $items)` and not `$items|foreach{}`, just to keep the variables used as verbose as possible.

Comment: @mklement0 you are correct, my bad. its fixed now :)